# Вывести индекс элемента из массива с объектами

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток.

Есть массив:

```
var fruits = [{type: 'Цитрус', name: 'Апельсин'},
             {type: 'Цитрус', name: 'Лимон'},
             {type: 'Семечковые', name: 'Яблоко'},
             {type: 'Косточковые', name: 'Абрикос'},
             {type: 'Семечковые', name: 'Груша'},
             ];

var search = 'Лимон';
```

Из этого массива мне нужно получить индекс, например, Лимона. Как осуществить поиск по этому массиву?

Array.prototype.indexOf() я так понял не подходит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эм.

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++)
    if (fruits[i].name == search) 
        alert(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно просто через цикл

```
function findElement(arr, sing) {
   for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      var element = arr[i];
      for(prop in element ) { if(element[prop] == sing) return i}
   }
   return -1; // если ничего не нашли
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот еще такой вариант.

```
var matrixArr = [];
function foobar(searchValue) {
    for (var i = 3; i > -1; i--){
        k = matrixArr[i].indexOf(+searchValue);
        if (k >= 0){
            return (i, k);
        } 
    }           
}
```

Comment: Можете пояснить ваше решение?

Comment: Да. Это частный случай для массива 4х4. (var matrixArr = [[,,,],
                 [,,,],
                 [,,,],
                 [,,,]];) Поиск идет с конца массива.  for (var i = 3; i > -1; i--){  - тут мы задаем номер массива с массивом. k = matrixArr[i].indexOf(+searchValue); - тут происходит поиск заданного числа +searchValue. Если .indexOf возвращает число более -1 - это наше искомое. Следующей строкой выводим его.

Answer (score 0):

Есть стандартный методы поиска элемента массива с определенным условием findIndex, используй его

```js
const fruits = [{
    type: 'Цитрус',
    name: 'Апельсин'
  },
  {
    type: 'Цитрус',
    name: 'Лимон'
  },
  {
    type: 'Семечковые',
    name: 'Яблоко'
  },
  {
    type: 'Косточковые',
    name: 'Абрикос'
  },
  {
    type: 'Семечковые',
    name: 'Груша'
  },
];

const LemonIndex = fruits.findIndex(fruit => fruit.name === 'Лимон')

console.log(LemonIndex)
```